# binary reading and writing complicated stucts in c++

Tags: c++, serialization, input, binary, output

I need the ability to save/read my data structures in my project, but all the data is in the form of quite complicated and distinct structures themselves which I typically implement through other structs and vectors. I have wrapped all of them up into a single struct so that I have something like

```
struct master{
    std::vector<apprentice_type1> a;
    std::vector<apprentice_type2> b; //etc.

    std::string label;
};
```

with other ones defined like

```
struct apprentice_type1{
    vec location;
    int point_label;
    std::vector<int> relational_data;
};

struct vec{
    double x,y,z;
};
```

So it gets pretty complicated! I was desperately hoping something nice, quick and naive like

```
master obj;
//write to obj....
std::ofstream ofs("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
ofs.write((char *)&obj, sizeof(obj));
```

would work, but at present it doesn't seem to. Before I get lost in the debugging rabbit hole is this actually possible the way I'm approaching it or do I need to rethink? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be a better approach, to write a `serialize(std::ostream&)` method for your `master` type. The vectors won't be serialized in a useful manner, the way you actually wrote your code.

Comment: Your hoped-for `ofs.write` call could not work because `obj` is not contiguous in memory. The `std::vector` members of your structures, for instance, allocate memory from the heap, so that isn't in the region from &obj -> (&obj + sizeof(obj)).

Comment: Use an existing serialization protocol (e.g. Google protocol buffers) and spare yourself the wheel reinvention.

Comment: Take a look at [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), it seems to have some on-the-shelf implementation to hold STL types, which may save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an alternative to Boost serialization and have access to a C++11 compiler, you can also check out [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/).  It works in a near identical fashion to Boost serialize but is a header only library so there is nothing to link against.

Comment: I like it. I'm using boost at the moment, but am having a hell of a time to get it to statically link so I might look at this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] or do I need to rethink? If so, how?

You will probably need to provide a full implementation (i.e. explore the "rabbit-hole").

This is a known problem (stream serialization) and there is no single best-approach solution to it, because most implementations need to solve different needs.

You can do one of the following:

- implement std::i/ostream serialization; This means you will go over your classes and implement `operator>>(std::istream*, your_type&)` and it's inverse `operator<<(std::ostream*, your_type&)`.
- implement serialization based on a stream library (like boost.archive).
- use a JSON or XML library.
- use google protocol buffers (or something else)
- roll your own implementation, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you go for boost::serialization, here is a little sample:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>


template <typename T>
inline const boost::serialization::nvp<T> archive_value(const char* name, T& value) {
    return boost::serialization::make_nvp(name, value);
}

const unsigned Version = 0;

class Point{
    public:
    double x,y,z;

    private:
    template <typename P, typename Archive>
    static void serialize(P& p, Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        std::cout << "Point\n";
        ar & archive_value("X", p.x);
        ar & archive_value("Y", p.y);
        ar & archive_value("Z", p.z);
    }

    public:
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        serialize(*this, ar, version);
    }

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        serialize(*this, ar, version);
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Point, Version)

struct Scene{
    std::vector<Point> points;

    private:
    template <typename S, typename Archive>
    static void serialize(S& s, Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        std::cout << "Scene\n";
        ar & archive_value("Points", s.points);
    }

    public:
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        serialize(*this, ar, version);
    }

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        serialize(*this, ar, version);
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Scene, Version)


template <typename Archive>
void register_types(Archive& ar) {
    ar.template register_type<Point>();
    ar.template register_type<Scene>();
}

int main() {
    Scene scene;
    scene.points = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 } };

    // Output
    {
        std::ofstream out("test.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive output(out);


        // First the version!
        output & archive_value("Version", Version);
        // Next the types!
        register_types(output);
        // Finally the data
        output & archive_value("Scene", scene);
    }

    scene.points = {};

    // Input
    {
        int version;
        std::ifstream in("test.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive input(in);
        // First the version!
        input & archive_value("Version", Version);
        // Next the types!
        register_types(input);
        // Finally the data
        input & archive_value("Scene", scene);
    }

    for(const auto& p : scene.points)
        std::cout << p.x << '\n';
}
```

Note: The file format may evolve and serialization functions (input and/or output) may get adjustment depending on the file version.

Comment: This looks really helpful. I've implemented it as best I can, but have two problems: When compiling and linking actually when writing and reading to/from a file "boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);" "oa << obj;" and "boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ofs);" all compile and link fine, but "ia>>object;" doesn't and I get lots of errors: I'm linking against -lboost_serialization am I missing anything? Also when setting up the ofstream I specify std::ios::binary but it still outputs in text form. Do I need a different boost function?

Comment: There are three (I guess) archive versions: text xml and binary - choose the binary one Note: use a boost::serialization::nvp<T> to pass objects `archive_value< ia >("Object", object);` (There is also a boost macro BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP, but I prefer setting the name manually)

Comment: Yes, you are right about the different options. I'm afraid I'm not so clear on your next point, I think I'm using a slightly different approach like the one found here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp and annoyingly that does compile for me so I'm tearing my hair out as to what I'm doing differently. I've compiled without the input and it outputs serialised data fine...

Comment: BOOST_CLASS_VERSION must be outside of any namespace (have a look at it's definition)

Comment: I just follow the documentation and write BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(struct_name,1) after the definition of each struct I serialise...

Comment: Also: If you have an assertion_failed look up the origin in the boost code - there might be an explanation.

Comment: Finally solved it: now working. FWIW had a rogue 'const' knocking about in a serialize function. At a loss as to why it compiled and ran fine with the output part. Anyway, thanks for all the help.